# how to display an array with child nodes in a tree format and use open and close button to that tree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

1. This is my javascript code to make the array object with child nodes
   in a tree format .but how to add the collapse button?
         $("document").ready(function () {
         for (i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
             $("#p_three").append("" + "- " + object[i].Name + "")
                   $("#p_three").append("");
             for (j = 0; j < object[i].children.length; j++) {
                 $("#p_three").append("" + "

   ```
   " + "    -- " + object[i].children[j].Name + "")
                 if (object[i].children[j].children == null) {
                     console.log("nope");
                 } else {
                     console.log("yes");
                     for (k = 0; k < object[i].children[j].children.length; k++) {
                         $("#p_three").append("" + "" + "       --- " + object[i].children[j].children[k].Name + "")
                         if (object[i].children[j].children[k].children == null) {
                             console.log("nope");
                         } else {
                             for (l = 0; l < object[i].children[j].children[k].children.length; l++) {
                                 $("#p_three").append("" + "" + "          ---- " + object[i].children[j].children[k].children[l].Name + "")
                             }
                         }
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         the current result is

   -a

     -b
          -c
          -d
     -f
     -g
          -h
          -i

     -j

   -k

     -l
          -m
     -n

          -o 
   I want buttons in such a way that at starting a,k should be visible,after clicking on a (b ,j) should be visible.And

   clicking g    should open (h,i).
   ```

   `$(document).ready(function () {
         $("#reset").click(function (e) {
             location.reload();
         });

         $("#treeview .parent").click(function (e) {
             e.stopPropagation();
             $(this).find(">ul").toggle("slow");
             if ($(this).hasClass("close"))
                 $(this).removeClass("close");
             else##`

   ---

   ##
                     $(this).addClass("close");
             });
         }); this is the jquery code i am using.

Answer (score 1):

1. $(function() {
       var $tree = $('#tree1');
       $tree.tree({
           data:array,

   ```
   });
   $tree.on(
       'tree.click',
       function(e) {
           // Disable single selection
           e.preventDefault();

           var selected_node = e.node;

           if (selected_node.id == undefined) {
               console.log('The multiple selection functions require that nodes have an id');
           }

       if ($tree.tree('isNodeSelected', selected_node)) {
           $tree.tree('removeFromSelection', selected_node);
       }
       else {
           $tree.tree('addToSelection', selected_node);

             cellValues.push(selected_node)
              console.log(cellValues);
       }
   }
   ```

   );